# X-Symfony-Cache always miss

Tags: php, apache, symfony, caching, utf-8

I'm working Symfony 2.6 HTTP cache, I'm following all the instructions in Symfony cook book [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/book/http_cache.html)

But, why the response always X-Symfony-Cache: MISS. I try to modification AppModification.php erase array on privates header. the response header is X-Symfony-Cache:GET /page: fresh.

After I modified array, I got new problem, while I'm trying to login to my web I got error or message the page isn't working.

here my code before erase array private header:

```
protected function getOptions()
{
    return array(
        'debug'                  => true,
        'default_ttl'            => 60,
        'private_headers'        => array('Authorization', 'Cookie'),
        'allow_reload'           => false,
        'allow_revalidate'       => false,
        'stale_while_revalidate' => 2,
        'stale_if_error'         => 60,
    );
}
```

Response Headers:

Cache-Control:private
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 29 Jun 2016 03:37:56 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.30
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.30
X-Symfony-Cache:GET /page: stale, invalid

I try to erase array private header

```
protected function getOptions()
{
    return array(
        'debug'                  => true,
        'default_ttl'            => 60,
        'private_headers'        => array(),
        'allow_reload'           => false,
        'allow_revalidate'       => false,
        'stale_while_revalidate' => 2,
        'stale_if_error'         => 60,
    );
}
```

Response Headers:

Age:2
Cache-Control:public, s-maxage=62
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:366990
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 29 Jun 2016 03:41:56 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.30
X-Content-Digest:en5ea0d5af1ee851007583987e8dfb3a8207874e303363f3d33c412b7f3fe6c12c
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.30
X-Symfony-Cache:GET /page: stale, invalid, store

anyone can help me, to suggest to solve this problem? I have no idea anymore, and can't find in any Symfony documentation.

Here my controller:

```
public function showDetailsAction( $pageSlug,request $request)
{
    $productManager = $this->get('my.core.manager.product');
    $product = $productManager->findOneProduct();
    $options =  $cmsManager->getSlugType($pageSlug);

    $memcacheKey = 'prodrelated_'.$productNumber;
    if($this->get('memcache.default')->get($memcacheKey)){
        $result = $this->get('memcache.default')->get($memcacheKey);
    }else{
        $cloudSearchManager   = $this->get('my.core.manager.cloudsearch');
        $result = $cloudSearchManager->findRelatedProductBy($options);            
        $this->get('memcache.default')->set($memcacheKey, $result, 0, 300);
    }

    $view = $this
        ->view()
        ->setTemplate("MyBundle:Product:detail.html.twig")
        ->setData(array(
            'product'   => $product
        ));

    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

Comment: Please show annotations of your `/page` action.

Comment: do you mean my controller?

Comment: Yeah, just to check if you've added `@Cache` annotation or properly modified your `Response` object

Comment: I'm just add my controller code

Comment: Try to add `$response = $view->getResponse(); $response->setPublic(); $response->setSharedMaxAge(600);` before return.

Comment: Yeah, i try that before and it's work. so, if I use appCache.php, I'm still need to setPublic in each controller?

Comment: Yes, or add `kernel.response` event listener and modify all responses in one place

Comment: I'm adding kernel response too, and it's not working. what do you mean with modify all response in one place?

Comment: I'm about http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-response-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Symfony Cache layer acts like an intermediary HTTP cache, much like a reverse proxy like Varnish would.

This means that for a response to be cacheable, it needs to be public (any cache can store it) and not private (only the browser cache may store it). Additionally, an appropriate caching strategy must be used, like a `max-age` in the Cache-Control header or an Expires header.

Comment: it's means I need to set max-age in each controller I have? Or there is global declaration to set public?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSHttpCacheBundle to simplify a global caching strategy.